# Converting string to SQLCommand

Tags: .net, vb.net, sqlcommand

I'm creating an app that has a text box where users can input a command to be run against a SQL Server instance. I've imported the `System.Data.SqlClient` object, and here's the code I have so far:

```
 Dim preSQLcmd As String = Me.txtPreSQL.Text
 Databasefn.preTestSQL(preSQLcmd)
```

`Databasefn.preTestSQL` looks like this:

```
Sub preTestSQL(cmd As SqlCommand)
    con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=" & utilnamespace.sqlSvr & ";Database=" & utilnamespace.testDbName & ";integrated security=SSPI;")
    cmd.Connection.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Connection.Close()
End Sub
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: That does not sound safe. `Delete From tableName` oh, no more data!

Comment: For how this app is gonna be used, that's absolutely fine. It's part of a test system, where the database is going to be restored after the tests are run anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `preTestSql` to receive the string with the sql command text and then build the **SqlCommand** inside the procedure

```
Sub preTestSQL(cmdText As String)
    using con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=" & utilnamespace.sqlSvr & ";Database=" & utilnamespace.testDbName & ";integrated security=SSPI;")
    using cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con)
         con.Connection.Open()
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Said that I should ask. **Are you sure that this is wise?**.

A malicious user could easily destroy your whole database with a functionality like that.

Examples:

```
 UPDATE PayRoll SET WeekWage = 1000  -- (no where condition??)
 DELETE FROM Employee
```

Comment: Yep, it's fine. This is an extremely limited use application that will only be used within our test system on a test database. The database is in no way production. I appreciate the thought though.

Comment: I'll definitely think about the security though, just in case it somehow gets leaked to someone outside the company, to make sure it can't be used to run something against some random db.

Comment: I'll definitely put thought into the security model around the app though. Thanks for asking, it's always good to revisit that stuff periodically.